# Importing of 3D STL Image in Python (ImportError: No module named ascii)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, import, 3d, numpy-stl

I am planning to write a program in Python for raspberrypi, to import a 3D STL image.

For that purpose, I googled and got a Python library called "[numpy-stl](https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl#stl-numpy)" which is suitable for my requirement. I install it according to the instructions of [website](https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl#installation)

```
sudo pip install numpy-stl
```

Then try to Run given [Code](https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl#quickstart) from example.

```
from stl import mesh

# Using an existing stl file:
mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('some_file.stl')

# Or creating a new mesh:
VERTICE_COUNT = 100
data = numpy.zeros(VERTICE_COUNT, dtype=Mesh.dtype)
mesh = mesh.Mesh(data, remove_empty_areas=False)

# The mesh normals (calculated automatically)
mesh.normals
# The mesh vectors
mesh.v0, mesh.v1, mesh.v2
# Accessing individual points (concatenation of v0, v1 and v2 in triplets)
mesh.points[0] == mesh.v0[0]
mesh.points[1] == mesh.v1[0]
mesh.points[2] == mesh.v2[0]
mesh.points[3] == mesh.v0[1]

mesh.save('new_stl_file.stl')
```

But now I am facing below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/checkstl.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stl import stl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stl/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import stl.ascii
ImportError: No module named ascii
```

Can anybody please guide me on how do I resolve this error?
Thank you

Comment: It looks like a problem with your installation of numpy-stl. Can you run the first line, `from stl import mesh`?

Comment: @ali_m I run it like this as well `from stl import mesh`  but still same above error facing

Comment: Something is broken about your installation then. Try removing and reinstalling numpy-stl, and see if any error messages appear during the installation.

Answer (score 4):

This should be solved once you update numpy-stl.
And more importantly, remove any other `stl` package - 
otherwise you have a clash with the module name. (The package numpy-stl is imported as `import stl`.)

If the package [stl 0.0.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stl/0.0.3) is installed, uninstall it first:

```
pip uninstall stl
```

Then the package [numpy-stl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-stl) should work as expected (i.e. it can be used via `import stl`), as soon as it is installed:

```
pip install numpy-stl
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain why your solution will solve the problem. An answer that just contains basic steps (even if they work) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: the answer is actually correct, the author simply has two packages installed that clash in terms of namespace. PS: I'm the author of numpy-stl and this isn't the first person with the problem

Comment: @Wolph needing to install a package `numpy-stl` for supporting a `import stl` is really confusing - and error prone, since there is also a package `stl`. The import for your package should be `import numpy-stl`.

Comment: @coproc that would result in an error, `numpy-stl` is not a valid import name ;) Ideally the abandoned `stl` package should be removed and replaced

Comment: @Wolph right: `numpy-stl` is not a valid module name ... but there would be other options ... e.g. `numpy_stl`?

Comment: True, but if I would change it now it would break code for a lot of people. The new version of numpy-stl (which I released about a week ago) does warn when you have a conflicting package installed

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you can do the same with [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (which I authored), except that it works for a whole range of mesh formats.

```
pip install meshio
```

```py
import meshio

mesh = meshio.read("input.stl")  # or .off, .vtk, .ply, ...
# mesh.points, mesh.cells, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just release the fastest, lightest and most intuitive library to handle STL files. It's called `openstl`. Check out the performance benchmarks against meshio, numpy-stl and more [here](https://github.com/Innoptech/OpenSTL).

```bash
pip install openstl
```

**Read and write from a STL file**

```py
import openstl
import numpy as np

# Define an array of triangles
# Following the STL standard, each triangle is defined with : normal, v0, v1, v2
quad = np.array([
    # normal,          vertices 0,      vertices 1,      vertices 2
    [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]], # Triangle 1
    [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]], # Triangle 2
])

# Write
success = openstl.write("quad.stl", quad, openstl.format.binary) # Or openstl.format.ascii (slower but human readable)

# Read
quad = openstl.read("quad.stl")
```

**Diverse operations**

```py
# Rotate
rotation_matrix = np.array([
    [0,-1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
])
rotated_quad = np.matmul(rotation_matrix, quad.reshape(-1,3).T).T.reshape(-1,4,3)

# Translate
translation_vector = np.array([1,1,1])
quad[:,1:4,:] += translation_vector # Avoid translating normals

# Scaling
scale = 1000.0
quad[:,1:4,:] *= scale # Avoid scaling normals

# Convert triangles to vertices and faces
vertices, faces = openstl.convert.verticesandfaces(triangles)
```